# Риторическое высказывание по принципу хрии

Tags: риторика, литературоведение

Пишу хрию. Тезис:  «Все счастливые семьи похожи друг на друга, каждая несчастливая семья несчастлива по-своему». Надо написать Противное.

Только не очень понимаю, как написать эту часть. Противное - Опровержение,
то есть доказательство от противного.

Вопрос: можно ли к этому тезису написать Противное? Если да, может кто-н. даст мысль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от того, хотите вы доказать или опровергнуть это утверждение Л. Н. Толстого.

Если доказать, то рассуждения могут выглядеть таким образом:
*Представим, что это **не так**, тогда получается, что счастливые семьи счастливы по-разному, а несчастные — одинаково. Однако, известно, что счастье появляется под воздействием гормона радости эндорфина, в то время как гормона несчастья не существует. Следовательно, проявление счастья не может сильно различаться у разных людей, а проявления несчастья могут быть самыми разными. Это приводит нас к противоречию, а поэтому мы можем утверждать, что обратный тезис некорректен.*

Если опровергнуть, то:
*Что такое несчастье в семейной жизни? Это непонимание семьёй друг друга. Жена не понимает мужа-тирана (тихоню, изменника, домоседа и т. п.), муж не понимает жену-тусовщицу (домоседку, истеричку, флегму и пр.), а дети не понимают, отчего родители ссорятся. Из этого непонимания рождаются явные или скрытые конфликты, которые и делают эти семьи несчастными.

В то время как в счастливых семьях всегда есть это понимание, но при этом само восприятие счастья в каждой семье различно. Для кого-то счастье — это иметь много денег, для других — вечно любить друг друга,   для третьих — прожигать жизнь в своё удовольствие, а чётвёртые счастливы, если супруг их не ограничивает. Таким образом, причина несчастья у всех одна, а причина счастья различается, поэтому мы можем считать утверждение Л. Н. Толстого неверным.*

Comment: Ой-ё! Я не сразу сообразила — кого "правлю". Ещё раз — извините!

Comment: @Римма Михайлова всё нормально, я такой же пользователь как и остальные, только с чуть большими правами. Ваши исправления я оставил на месте.

Comment: Да, я заметила. Спасибо за "положительность".